# JavaFX animation slow moving image

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I'm trying to make a scrolling background; the hope is to connect it end to tail, so that it rotates the same "ribbon" around, and I place this at the back of my game.

I've been seeking the right way to achieve animating this. I can use an AnimationTimer as per my example, or a TimeLine. However, I want to move the animation speed much slower, and delaying updates to the timer causes jerking. I did add an int variable, which returns if less than "x" millis has passed, but it didn't look good.

What is a better way to accomplish this task?

```
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

class ImageContainer extends VBox {
    int w, h;
    int sectionScrollWidth = 1;
    int sections;
    int sectionCounter = 0;
    Image image;
    Canvas canvas;

public ImageContainer() {
    setVisible(true);
    load();
    w = (int) image.getWidth();
    h = (int) image.getHeight();
    canvas = new Canvas(w, h);
    getChildren().add(canvas);
    sections = w / sectionScrollWidth;
    GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
    canvas.setVisible(true);
    gc.drawImage(image, 0, 0, w, h);
    setPrefSize(w, h);

    final long startNanoTime = System.nanoTime();

    new AnimationTimer() {
        public void handle(long currentNanoTime) {
            sectionCounter = sectionCounter - sectionScrollWidth;
            canvas.setTranslateX(sectionCounter);
        }
    }.start();

//        KeyValue kv1 = new KeyValue(canvas.translateXProperty(), 0);
//        KeyValue kv2 = new KeyValue(canvas.translateXProperty(), 2000);
//        KeyFrame kf1 = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(3000), kv1, kv2);
//        Timeline translate = new Timeline();
//        translate.getKeyFrames().add(kf1);
//        translate.play();

}

public void load() {
    Path imagePath = Paths.get("./src/main/resources/ribbonImages/clouds.png");
    File f = imagePath.toFile();
    assert f.exists();
    image = new Image(f.toURI().toString());
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (((System.nanoTime()-startNanoTime)/1000000000.0)<0.05) {
                return;
            }
            else {
                startNanoTime = System.nanoTime();
            }
```

Added to the handle() method will force it to return if less than 0.05 secs have passed. Fairly obvious answer, but I didn't want to just delete my own question, in case this helps someone else.